# Criação de tabelas flask-sqlalchemy

Tags: python, flask

Estou desenvolvendo uma pequena aplicação em Flask e estou utilizando as extensões Flask-SQLAlchemy, Flask-Migrate e Flask-Script para gerenciar minhas migrações no banco de dados, segue a configuração do meu aplicativo.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_migrate import Migrate, MigrateCommand
from flask_script import Manager
from flask_login import LoginManager
from flask_mail import Mail
import coverage
import os
import unittest


# Aplicativo
app = Flask(__name__)

# Configurações
app.config.from_object(os.environ['APP_SETTINGS'])

# Database
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

# Migrações
migrate = Migrate(app, db)

# Manager
manager = Manager(app)
manager.add_command('db', MigrateCommand)

# Autenticação
login = LoginManager(app)
login.login_view = 'login'

# Mail
mail = Mail(app)

# Importações
from app import routes
from users import views, models

# Blueprints
app.register_blueprint(views.bp)
```

Eu inicio o banco de dados com `flask db init`, crio a migração com `flask db migrate` e atualizo o banco de dados com `flask db upgrade` o problema é que ao tentar utilizar o banco de dados ecebo o seguinte erro:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError

sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) no such table: users [SQL: 'INSERT INTO users (username, password_hash, email) VALUES (?, ?, ?)'] [parameters: ('thiago', 'pbkdf2:sha256:50000$OINivJRi$d81223e55b8b4ef150c49c251c2007b756efa5cef51ed8bbdde66c263e20f2cf', 'tth*****@gmail.com')] (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/e3q8)
```

Quando eu então entro numa sessão do shell do flask e faço um db.create_all() o banco de dados functiona, mas é realmente necessário fazer isso manualmente? Se sim em qual arquivo devo fazer isso?

Comment: O problema é que a tabela não foi criada antes de você tentar inserir os dados. Você verificou se a primeira migração gerada pelo `flask-migrate` está criando essas tabelas? Como estão umas migrações?

Answer (score 1):

poste o arquivo responsavel pela iniciar o projeto, geralmente ao usuar o flask-script, o arquivo responsavel por iniciar a aplicaçao, é mais ou menos  assim :

*arquivo run.py*

```
from app import manager

if __name__=='__main__':
    manager.run()
```

para fazer a migraçao :
 python run.py db init
 python run.py db migrate

ou seja au usar o flask-script nao é necessario usar flask run.py db init etc, o  proprio manager ira fazer isso.